# Modules installed with Composer placed in wrong directory

Tags: installation, 8, composer

I'm trying to install modules via Composer. I've set up my `composer.json` file according to Drupal.org's direction. However, the installed modules are being placed inside of `vendor/drupal/`. I'm new to Drupal 8, so I wouldn't be surprised if this is a result of a simple mistake. I'll include my `composer.json` file below:

```
{
    "repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.19"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably missing dependency for composer/installers and potentially drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per what [Ivan Jeros](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/21641/ivan-jaros) said, if you add "composer/installers": "^1.2" to your "require" array, it will add a composer extention that maps to the directories you added:

```
"require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
```

Otherwise, it puts everything in /vender/drupal

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like your composer.json file is getting read. It's possible having multiple composer files. Are you running your commands from the base folder of your project, beside `composer.json`.

The download directories can customized to match your Drupal layout. For example, this is a popular configuration from Acquia:

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "docroot/core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "docroot/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "docroot/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "docroot/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: I'm running composer commands from the root directory, and the paths look correct. Also, when I run `composer require drupal/<module>`, composer adds the module name and version number to the composer.json file, which indicates to me that it is reading it. Unless, there is something wrong with how I'm formatting the "extra" array.